# Error in SQL syntax, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Someone help me please. I have a problem in my codes, the error says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'longitude=' at line 1".

Here's my code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$id=isset($_SESSION['id']);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT sms_text FROM sms_in where id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$gps= mysql_fetch_array($sql);

preg_match('/lat:(\d+\.\d+) /', $gps, $matches);
unset($matches[0]);
$params = array(
    'f' => 'q',
    'q' => implode(',', $matches),
    'z' => 16,
);
$query1 = '//maps.google.com/maps?' . http_build_query($params);

$query = array();
$urlParts = parse_url($query1);
parse_str($urlParts['query'], $query);

//echo $query['q'];
//Get longitude

$sql4 = mysql_query("SELECT sms_text FROM sms_in where id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$gps1= mysql_fetch_array($sql);

preg_match('/long:(\d+\.\d+) /', $gps1, $matches1);
unset($matches1[0]);
$params1 = array(
    'f' => 'q',
    'q' => implode(',', $matches1),
    'z' => 16,
);
$query2 = '//maps.google.com/maps?' . http_build_query($params1);

$query3 = array();
$urlParts1 = parse_url($query2);
parse_str($urlParts1['query'], $query3);

//echo $query3['q'];
//$sql5="select id
```

---> //this one the cause of error

```
$sql2= mysql_query("Insert into tbl_location SET latitude=$query[q],longitude=$query3[q]")
        or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you highlighted the line which was causing the error, rather then having to scroll through your whole code to find its at the bottom

Comment: @NoLiver92 i do agree with you but kind of obvious at a sql syntax error where the error is.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem in your insert query, it should be like...

```
INSERT INTO tbl_location (latitude,longitude) VALUES ('$query[q]','$query3[q]')
```

You must need to follow below syntax of Insert query.

**[INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) Syntax**

```
INSERT
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Comment: but the values are Double not varchar

Comment: Then omit the quotes. Also, if the brackets are a problem use `${query[q]}`to better declare the variable. Even more better would be to stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and use mysqli or PDO objects and prepared statements.

Comment: @arianne there is a problem in your insert query syntax as i stated my answer, no-mater its in double or in varchar

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I omitted quotes earlier sir, im just trying if it will work.

Comment: @SumitBijvani Not yet sir.

Comment: @SumitBijvani Yes sir :(

Comment: @loko "14.674518" this sir, it was from the database originally this "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=14.674518%2C120.549043&z=16"

Comment: @arianne are latitude and longitude the only columns in the table?

Comment: @arianne which data type you are using to store values ?

Comment: No sir, there are five.

Comment: @arianne and what is the length of it?

Comment: @arianne Use `DECIMAL(10,7)`. Where `10` is the total number of digits in the number and `7` is the number of digits after the .. (This means that before the dot will be 3 digits.)

Comment: @arianne `DOUBLE(10,7)` try it

Comment: Ok sir, i just use it now.

Comment: @SumitBijvani Nothing's change

Answer (score 2):

You are using the insert query wrong. You are using it as if it is the update query at this line:

```
$sql2= mysql_query("Insert into tbl_location SET latitude=$query[q],longitude=$query3[q]")
```

use it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Source:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html MySQL does allow `INSERT INTO table SET column=value [,column2=value2]`. Must admit I'd always used the format you suggested, but the `SET` will work.

Comment: @danielpsc Ow haha never knew that! Learned something today. Thanks

Comment: Yep, it was new on me too!

Comment: @danielpsc I dont get it, How can you INSERT INTO table set="..." without a WHERE to use SET? SET would be totally useless?

Comment: They're just equivalents. `INSERT INTO table (field, field2) VALUES (value, value2)` is the same as `INSERT INTO table SET field= value, field2= value2`. My guess is that it's only there so that INSERTs and UPDATEs can use the same structure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this line:

```
$sql2= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_location (latitude,longitude) VALUES ('" . $query['q'] . "','" . $query3['q'] ."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir but the return value becomes 0.

Answer (score 0):

try using `` to help engine understand

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_location`"."(latitude,longitude)". "VALUES". "('$query[q]','$query3[q]')";
```

Comment: That was a big help! Thank you sir.